# return a rust-wasm vector in angular application

Tags: angular, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have a basic angular app and a Rust wasm pack, and I want to call functions in the Rust compiled code in angular.
The rust code template is taken from [the rust-pack-template-repo](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template) in `lib.rs` is the following:

```
mod utils;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;


#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add_one(number: u32) -> u32
{
   number + 1
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn test_vec_output(num_samples: u32) -> Vec<u32>
{
  let my_vec: Vec<u32> = vec![12; num_samples as usize];

  my_vec
}
```

In the Angular app side, I used the following code sample to call the rust-wasm function:

```
async testRustWasmFunctions()
{
import('../wasm-test-pack/pkg/myDummyPackage_bg.wasm').then((response) => {
      this.myFirstResult = response.add_one(1);
      console.log("Test dummy add: " + this.myFirstResult); // Works fine !! returns 2
      console.log("Test dummy vector: " + response.test_vec_output(1,1)); // Only works if I take two arguments
    });
}
```

In the HTML part the function is called like this:

```
<button (click)="testRustWasmFunctions()"><\button>
```

The `response.test_vec_output(1,1))` function call returns no error (in angular) when called with two arguments, and the console result returns *undefined*. While the function `add_one` works just fine and returns the correct result.

Is there a better way to import rust-wasm pack to angular than this, such that it is easy to process vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wasm-bindgen` generates a js file (should be called `myDummyPackage.js`) which is responsible for setting up a bunch of stuff (like heap and wrappers).

You can try to import generated `.js` file, if it doesn't work I recommend looking at these tutorials:

- This [tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/without-a-bundler.html#without-a-bundler) to get an ES module (you should use `wasm-pack --target web` for this)
- This [tutorial](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/hello-world.html#webpack-specific-files) to setup webpack

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to convert your `Vec<u32>` to a [js_sys::Uint32Array](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.45/js_sys/struct.Uint32Array.html). So your `test_vec_output` would look like:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn test_vec_output(num_samples: u32) -> js_sys::Uint32Array {
    let my_vec: Vec<u32> = vec![12; num_samples as usize];
    return js_sys::Uint32Array::from(&my_vec[..]);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, I already came across a post suggesting a similar solution, I have high doubts about the ways I am integrating the wasm to angular is the source of the problem, still looking for concrete examples using angular

Comment: I don't think its related to angular. Did you get it working on a plain ts project ?